# Missing something with FCM Configuration

Tags: android

I'm Trying for FCM and getting failed to add **apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'** in **build.gradle**(app level). The android studio show the Error

[image]

List of JDK's I have.
[image]

Today on 23 June, I have solved this problem for 1 step more, and now the error is as shown here:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing what it tells you to do?..

Comment: Yes i did tried all the three options. Even a JDK version is same.

Comment: Try updating to 7u79

Comment: Add more details. All java files of src, gradle app and project level, manifest.xml. Then it will be easy to help you.

Comment: copy your gradle file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing latest version of [jdk from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) 8u111.

And compile using this library:

> **compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0"** with buildToolsVersion **'23.0.1'**